# How to automatically answer yes in a dialog box in VB script?

Tags: vbscript

How to automatically answer yes in a dialog box in VB script ?

Comment: A dialog box is designed for human interaction.  If you need to simulate a user clicking it then you're probably either doing something fundamentally wrong or something malicious.

Comment: Or he trying to do automated testing.

Answer (score 2):

SendKeys might do what you want:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Ehh...very hit or miss in my experience, but you are right that it is as close as vbscript comes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) instead (or something similar). VBScript does not provide the way to do this natively.